# When start strict mode and set `android:persistent` to `true` will has error. How can I fix this error?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, android-strictmode

When start strict mode and set `android:persistent` to `true` will has error. How can I fix this error? Thanks.

**Application**

```
override fun onCreate() {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        setStrictMode()
    }
    super.onCreate()
}

private fun setStrictMode() {
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectDiskReads()
            .detectDiskWrites()
            .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems
            .penaltyLog()
            .build())
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
            .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()
            .detectLeakedClosableObjects()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDeath()
            .build())
}
```

**preference_example.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <SwitchPreference
            android:key="switch_preference_night_mode"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:title="@string/theme_settings_night_mode" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

**PreferenceFragment:**

```
public class ThemeSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference_example, rootKey);
    }
}
```

**Error log:**

```
StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=30 ms: android.os.strictmode.DiskReadViolation
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1500)
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.checkAccess(UnixFileSystem.java:251)
        at java.io.File.exists(File.java:815)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getDataDir(ContextImpl.java:2237)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getPreferencesDir(ContextImpl.java:550)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferencesPath(ContextImpl.java:747)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:400)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:174)
        at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:330)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` are read from the disk the first time they are accessed and then cached in memory, hence your `DiskReadViolation` in strict mode.

While running all I/O as non-blocking off the main thread is ideal, even if you enable strict mode on Google Apps you will see red flashes at app start-up so you may not easily be able to get around your strict-mode violation.

The main thing for you to be concerned about is long-running HTTP requests or long-running database operations running on the main thread - these are to be avoided and the solutions involve using something like `AsyncTask`, RxJava or Kotlin coroutines.

For now, the `SharedPreference` and the associated `setPreferenceFromResource` have a modes of operation that you do not control and so you are unlikely to make things better by adding asynchronous code around these.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other answer, there's nothing you can do about this. But, this shouldn't prevent you from using `StrictMode` on other parts of the app. To ignore a specific code path from `StrictMode`, use this pattern:

```java
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState,
            @Nullable String rootKey
    ) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy originalPolicy = StrictMode.allowThreadDiskReads();
        try {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
        } finally {
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(originalPolicy);
        }
    }
```